# TimeStep do not iterate | Box2D

Tags: c++, box2d

i am getting back to box2d after many years of absence and thought to start from zero. on top of that decided to work with the C++ version this time (in the past worked with the Javascript version)

For a reason the very first program described in box2d.org does not run properly. When i compile it i do not get any errors however the result is wrong.

The result is 0.00 4.00 0.00 and remains as such.
But with each iteration of timestep, the position.y should decrease (position.x and angle should remain the same)

```
#include "include/box2d/box2d.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

    
int main(){
  b2Vec2 gravity(0.0f, -10.0f); // define the gravity vector
  b2World world(gravity);       //create the world object

//Creating static Ground Body
  b2BodyDef groundBodyDef;      //body definition
    groundBodyDef.position.Set(0.0f, -10.0f);

  b2Body* groundBody = world.CreateBody(&groundBodyDef); // body definition is passed to the world object to create the ground body

  b2PolygonShape groundBox;    //create a ground polygon.
    groundBox.SetAsBox(50.0f, 10.0f);   //We use the SetAsBox shortcut to form the ground polygon into a box shape

  groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBox, 0.0f);  //creating the shape fixture

//Creating Dynamic Body
  b2BodyDef bodyDef;
  bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;  //By default bodies are static, so we should set the b2BodyType at construction time to make the body dynamic
  bodyDef.position.Set(0.0f, 4.0f);
  b2Body* body = world.CreateBody(&bodyDef);

  b2PolygonShape dynamicBox;    //create a box shap
  dynamicBox.SetAsBox(1.0f, 1.0f);
//A dynamic body should have at least one fixture with a non-zero density. Otherwise you will get strange behavior.
  b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;    // fixture definition using the box
  fixtureDef.shape = &dynamicBox;
  fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
  fixtureDef.friction = 0.3f;

  float timeStep = 1.0f / 60.0f;  //Integrators simulate the physics equations at discrete points of time -> ie timeStep

  int32 velocityIterations = 6;
  int32 positionIterations = 2;

  for (int32 i = 0; i < 60; ++i)  {
      world.Step(timeStep, velocityIterations, positionIterations);
      b2Vec2 position = body->GetPosition();
      float angle = body->GetAngle();
      printf("%4.2f %4.2f %4.2f\n", position.x, position.y, angle);
  }

      //return 0;
}
```

Apologies for the noobie question, but cannot find my mistake. i almost copy paste everything!

Answer (score 0):

I actually forgot to include body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);